# How to do %in% by rows in R?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a basic function or function in data.table that can help me do this? I'm looking for an efficient way to deal with big data.

For example:

```
matrix A:
a b
a c
d b
d a

matrix B:
a b
d c
a d
```

B %in% A should return `T,F,F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are indeed dealing with `data.table` (not clear from OP), this is one possibility:

```
A = data.table(c('a','a','d','d'),c('b','c','b','a'))
B = data.table(c('a','d','a'), c('b','c','d'))

setkey(A, V1, V2)

A[B, .N, by = .EACHI] # in data.table <= 1.9.2 use A[B, .N]
#   V1 V2 N
#1:  a  b 1
#2:  d  c 0
#3:  a  d 0
```

You can then do whatever you want with column `N`, including converting it to logical if you like:

```
as.logical(A[B, .N, by = .EACHI]$N)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: `A[B, which=TRUE]` as well.. (not straightforward though).

Comment: @Arun nice - I've never used `which` before

Comment: I'm not good at data.table. So when can I omit the "by" parameter in the []?

Comment: @3zhang you can omit it for `data.table` version 1.9.2 and below; for version after that the by-without-by feature has been made explicit

Answer (score 1):

`apply(B, 1, list) %in% apply(A, 1, list)`

works for both matrices and data.tables (and data.frames).

## Example

```
A <- cbind(c('a','a','d','d'), c('b','c','b','a'))
B <- cbind(c('a','d','a'), c('b','c','d'))
apply(B, 1, list) %in% apply(A, 1, list)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
identical(.Last.value, apply(data.table(B), 1, list) %in% apply(data.table(A), 1, list))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a `data.table` solution to me

Comment: It works for sure, it just not a `data.table` solution as the OP requested. See @eddies answer

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the original version of the question--edited within whatever SO's grace period is for hiding edits--referred to the data as being matrices. Robert's answer is totally acceptable.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, you are just arguing with me for the sake of it, ain't you :)

Comment: This is helpful. Just wondering whether this is efficient enough to deal with large dataset.

Comment: @3zhang, in general, it's important to make your question *complete*. From your Q, it's not clear whether you use a `matrix`, or a `data.table`, and whether your data is large or not. By providing a complete question, these exchanges can be avoided! In any case, read `%\`in%\`` section where it says: "matching for lists is potentially very slow...".

Comment: @Arun Sorry to make things unclear. But is there a big difference between using matrix and using data.table? I mean I can convert a matrix to data.table and after processing convert it back to a matrix. I think it shouldn't take me too much time to convert between these two structures.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility: Use `duplicated` and `rbind`. Using @Robert's sample data:

```
A <- cbind(c('a','a','d','d'), c('b','c','b','a'))
B <- cbind(c('a','d','a'), c('b','c','d'))
duplicated(rbind(B, unique(A)), fromLast = TRUE)[1:nrow(B)]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a good method for small dataset. But for large one the unique function itself is slow from my knowledge.

Comment: @3zhang, how large are your data? `matrix`? `data.frame`? `data.table`? Some classes have their own methods which may make them faster than others. Also, looking at my answer again, I guess you don't really need the `unique` step.